# I'm trying to run a basic Android-NDK project in android studio on windows but keep getting unknown file error

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\Simran\De
sktop\BTP\Camera\app\jni;/jni/Android.mk
C:/Users/Simran/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-application.mk:199: **
* Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

My Android.mk file is inside the jni folder already.

Edit- I've already added the ndk path to my Path variables and I'm running the ndk-build command from my project directory.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error with a fresh install of Android Studio 1.3.2, ndk-bundle installed from sdk manager, and opening a working ndk project from a previous Android Studio installation.

On checking the setup of a fresh project for some clues, got a warning that there were spaces in my project path.

After removing the spaces from the project path, the ndk error disappeared and the project runs as before.

Not sure if will be the same issue, but is something to check.